# emacs-project-mode shows issues when starting with --debug-init

Tags: macos, emacs, lisp, init

On OSX have downloaded emacs-project-mode into my load path.

https://code.google.com/p/emacs-project-mode/
http://emacs-project-mode.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/project-mode.el

I added the following part to my .emacs.d/init.el (According to the installation instructions the .emacs file should be modified, however I don't have an .emacs file, and instead add everything to my init.el)

```
(require 'project-mode)
(project-load-all) ; Loads all saved projects. Not required.
```

The mode seems to be working as I can see the various functions when `M-x project-`

However when debugging my init.el using `emacs --debug-init` I get

```
debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ".")
...
```

On various places in project-mode.el

e.g

```
Line 478: not already been processed using `TAGS-FORM'."       
Line 761: (not (string-equal ".." looking-at)))
```

The line look valid to me, so I'm wondering why emacs reports them as errors?

Comment: My guess is this is because it is inside `defun*` and `defun*` wasn't required at load time. Perhaps would try if you added `(eval-when (:load) (require 'cl))`

Comment: This package seems to be dead.  The last commit was three years ago.  You may want to look at a modern alternative, such as [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)